# Is there a mitzvah not to ignore a person?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, messiah, agada-stories-legends, derech-eretz-manners

BH

This probably very common sense question although what is the mitzvah that when your with a person you shouldn’t ignore them? What’s the source?

Comment: Maybe the Gemara that says Rabbi Yochanan Ben Zakkai used to greet everybody he saw on the street

Comment: Vahavta lreacha komocha

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara says:

> One who does not respond to a greeting is called a robber. [Berakhot 6b]

Comment: Υet, Abba Hilkiah did not respond to the sages sent to him, when they greeted him (Taanit 23a-b; H/T Mesilat Yesharim ch. 11).

Comment: -1 This neither answers "Is there _a mitzvah_ not to _ignore_ a person" ((a) it doesn't say whether a mitzvah is involved, and (b) one can easily refrain from responding to another person's greeting, even when talking to him), nor "what _is_ the mitzvah that when your with a person you shouldn’t ignore them". To the extent the OP asked "what’s the source", it was in the context of those questions.